# Que veut dire « il joue la caille de cité » ?

Tags: sens, argot

Excusez moi, car le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle, mais j'aimerais bien apprendre en lisant des commentaires un peu partout, et voilà !
J'étais en train de lire les commentaires ici: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iFm38gJo0E , et j'ai trouvé ce passage

> À quel moment il joue la « caille de cité » ?

Que veut dire « il joue la caille de cité » ? Est-ce que cette phrase peut avoir un sens vulgaire ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C'est du français parlé, pas spécifiquement vulgaire; « **ce** (*sic*) **l'a** (*sic*) **jouer caille de cité** » veut dire :

> se la jouer « racaille de cité »

[**se la jouer**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_la_jouer) = prétendre être, se faire passer pour...

**racaille de cité** ~= voyou de banlieue

- [**racaille**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/racaille) a donné [**caillera**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/caillera) en [verlan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan), puis **caille** (<s>diminutif</s> apocope)
- **cité** = ici groupe d'immeubles dans quartiers populaires.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: Je n'aurais jamais pu le deviner, j'aurais pensé que ça voulait dire _douillet_, j'aurais lu ça comme _poule mouillée de cité_ ou qqc. comme ça ! Merci !

Comment: @Qu'arrhesrententsanshune Oui, c'est de l'argot et la collision avec le volatile homographe ne facilite pas la compréhension…

Comment: "caille" n'est pas un diminutif de "racaille" car un diminutif ne diminue pas le nom mais la chose désignée par ce nom. Une "caille" n'est pas une "petite racaille", alors qu'une fleurette serait une petite fleur, par exemple.

Comment: @Distic Corrigé. Merci !